# Generate image URL in an initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, asset-pipeline

How can I generate an image URL from an initializer? I'm trying to accommodate [this gem](https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag)'s configuration for setting a default image in its configuration. I'd like to reference it through the asset system so that it works in development and production. I actually was first trying to make it work just in production mode but I can't get that working either.

Here's what I've hacked together so far.

```
class DefaultGravatarImage
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
  default_url_options[:host] = Rails.configuration.host

  def initialize(image_name)
    @image_name = image_name
  end

  def to_s
    path_to_image(@image_name)
  end
end

GravatarImageTag.configure do |config|
  config.default_image = DefaultGravatarImage.new("default_avatar.png").to_s
end
```